# UIImageView from array and touch? for IPhone

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

i have this method
Code:

```
- (void)addImageSubViewAtX:(CGFloat)x atY:(CGFloat)y {
  CGRect myImageRect1 = CGRectMake(x, y, 30.0f, 30.0f); 
  myImage1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect1]; 
  [myImage1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"status_finish.gif"]]; 
  [self.view addSubview:myImage1];

}
```

now i am using this to call images
Code:

```
[self addImageSubViewAtX:160.0 atY:190.0];
```

and

```
[self addImageSubViewAtX:10.0 atY:190.0];
```

but touch method is working only on 1 image not both

Code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 
     UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject]; 
     CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self.view]; 
     if (CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake(myImage1.frame.origin.x, myImage1.frame.origin.y, myImage1.frame.size.width, myImage1.frame.size.height ), p)) 
     { 
         [pieMenu showInView:self.view atPoint:p]; 
     }
}
```

how to make this touch working for both of them

Comment: You would be more likely to get answers if you formatted your code to be more readable. Look at the formatting guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,

you are calling 2 times the `- (void)addImageSubViewAtX:(CGFloat)x atY:(CGFloat)y` - Method.

In this method you're setting the pointer of myImage1 to a new instance of a UIImageView.
So myImage1 is the reference to the last UIImageView you have added.

Thats why it just works for one imageView.

Answer (score 0):

You are reinitializing the the same image view (myImage1) in your addImageSubViewAtX method not creating and adding a new one. So only the latest image view is accessed in the touch method when you use myImage1.

Instead add a new image view every time. Give it a particular tag before adding and check for a touch on the view with that tag.

Something like :

```
- (void)addImageSubViewAtX:(CGFloat)x atY:(CGFloat)y {
  CGRect myImageRect1 = CGRectMake(x, y, 30.0f, 30.0f); 
  UIImageView myImage1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect1]; 
  [myImage1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"status_finish.gif"]];
  myImage1.tag = 1000;
  [self.view addSubview:myImage1];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 
 UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject]; 
 if ([[touch view] tag] == 1000) 
 { 
     [pieMenu showInView:self.view atPoint:p]; 
 }
}
```

Comment: AMAZING  WOW GR8  HATS OFF YOU MADE MY DAY :-)  I WAS STRUGGLING FOR 3 HRS DAAM

Comment: Don't forget to release myImage1 at the end of the method "addImageSubViewAtX..."